# Django/Python: How to get the latest value from a model queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have created a model 'VehicleDetails' in which a user can fill the details of a vehicle and another model 'TripStatus' in which he can update the vehicle location. I wanted to get the latest location for which I did as in my below code. But when i running the server, it returns all the values not the latest value. I would appreciate helping me solve this or suggesting a new approach.

models.py:

```
class VehicleDetails(models.Model):
    Vehicle_No = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class TripStatus(models.Model):
    vehicledetails = models.ForeignKey(VehicleDetails, related_name='tripstatuss')
    CHOICES = (('Yet to start', 'Yet to start'),('Trip starts', 'Trip starts'), ('Chennai','Chennai'), ('Vizag', 'Vizag'), ('Kolkata', 'Kolkata'))
    Vehicle_Status = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, default="Yet to start", max_length=20)
    statustime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

views:

```
def status(request):
    tripstatus = TripStatus.objects.all().latest('statustime')
    context = {
    "tripstatus": tripstatus,
}
    return render(request, 'loggedin_load/active_deals.html', context)
```

template:

```
{% for status in vehicledetails.tripstatuss.all %}
{{status.Vehicle_Status}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: There are some important parts of code that not presented in question. You pass `'tripstatus'` to template, but in the template looping over `vehicledetails.statuses` which you didn't pass.

Answer (score 0):

Should just have to remove the .all():

```
tripstatus = TripStatus.objects.latest('statustime')
```

Or maybe:

```
tripstatus = TripStatus.order_by('-statustime').first()
```

Comment: it still returns all the values.

Comment: does using the order_by version change?

Comment: same result. Even i use aggregate(Max('statustime')). Everything results in displaying all values, not latest one.

Comment: are you sure you are displaying the correct dataset? What happens if you len() the `tripstatus`? Check @vishes_shell's comment.

Comment: It returns the number of instances in TripStatus model. Here my problem is i couldn't able to get the latest value. Instead, it displays all values for a particular vehicle.

Comment: I forget to change the template as {% vehicledetails.tripstatuss.all %} when i posted the question. Sorry for that.